# delegate contravariance (parameter compatibility)

Tags: c#, c#-5.0

I am looking at the `C# 5 in a Nutshell` text, section on Delegate Parameter Compatibility. It says

> When you call a method, you can supply arguments that have more specific types than the parameters of that method. This is ordinary polymorphic behavior. For exactly the same reason, a delegate can have more specific parameter types than its method target. This is called *contravariance*.

This paragraph makes sense up until the last sentense. Why is it *contravariance*, i.e. what projection here is contravariant?

The accompanying example is below.

```
delegate void StringAction (string s);

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        StringAction sa = new StringAction (ActOnObject);
        sa ("hello");
    }

    static void ActOnObject (object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (o); // hello
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The projection of `object` (the parameter of the function `ActionObject`) to the type declared for the delegate (`string`) is contravariant.

This is allowed because by passing it a string (which you must due to the delegate signature), you are guaranteed that you will have an `object` (which the assigned function takes), so everything is nice and safe.

Just so you know, "ordinary polymorphism" in this context is actually called **covariance**.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Comment: I'm confused because when you invoke `StringAction` with `string` argument, that argument gets upcast to `object` when it gets to the target method. So we're going from `string` to `object` and not the other way around. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @async You have it exactly right. In this case, it is contravariant primarily because it is on the parameter, which isn't allowed to be covariant (specifically on interfaces). Its a little more apparent which direction it is going on a interface as well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174.aspx has another example very similar to the one you posted.

Answer (score 3):

Function types are contravariant in argument types. In your example the type

```
delegate void ObjectAction(object o);
```

is a subtype of

```
delegate void StringAction(string s);
```

since `ObjectAction` can be used everywhere that `StringAction` is used because, if a caller is passing in a `string` argument, the argument must also be of type `object`.

`object` is a supertype of `string` but `ObjectAction` is a subtype of `StringAction`; the subtyping goes in the opposite direction. This is why it's called contravariant. Because the variation in the function subtypes goes in the opposite direction of the parameter subtypes.